# condition evaluating to "TRUE"

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, scripting

I am trying to check for duplicate records in my database using shell scripting.
For this, I have created a function named "check()" which echo's True or False and is stored in variable "result". But while evaluating using if statement it is always returning "True".

```
#redundancy check function
check() {
    temp=$(grep -w -c "$1" database.dat)
    echo $temp
    if [ "$temp" != 0 ]
        then
            echo True
        else
            echo False
    fi
}

insert() {
    option="y"
    while [ "$option" == "y" ]
    do
        echo "Rollno: \c"
        read roll
        result="$(check $roll)"
        echo $result
        if [ "$result" == "False" ]
            then        
                echo Do something
            else
                echo "ERROR: Duplicate record found...\nEXITING...\n"
                option="n"
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: FYI, the only string comparison operator specified in POSIX `test` is `=`, not `==`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Also, what `\n` will do inside a string passed to `echo` is not specified by POSIX (some noncompliant versions of `echo` support a `-e` argument to make `echo` process such escapes; others process them by default; others don't process it at all). Using `printf` if you want consistent behavior.

Comment: Also note you are comparing string to int. Use `$((temp)) -ne 0` instead

Comment: well -- it'd be better to avoid `grep -c` (or, otherwise, a `grep` without `-q` or an equivalent extension such as GNU's `-m 1`) altogether. Using it so forces `grep` to read through the entire `database.dat` to count all matches, but the OP only wants to know if the number of matches is zero or not -- meaning that if the very first line is a match, `grep -q` can exit immediately when it's seen without having to read any other content in the file, whereas `grep -c` still needs to read all the other lines to generate its count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a shell that doesn't support the `==` extension to `test`, then your tests will always, unconditionally fail simply on account of invalid syntax. Use `=` for string comparisons to be portable to all POSIX-compliant implementations.

Moreover, there's no point to storing and then comparing the output from `grep` at all: Use the exit status of `grep -q` when your only goal is to check whether the number of matches is zero or more-than-zero; this allows `grep` to exit immediately when a match is seen, rather than needing to read the rest of the file.

```
# with -q, this emits no stdout, but exits w/ status 0 (matches exist) or 1 (otherwise)
check() { grep -q -w -e "$1" database.dat; }

insert() {
  option=y
  while [ "$option" = y ]; do
    printf '%b\n' "Rollno: \c"
    read -r roll
    if check "$roll"; then
      printf "ERROR: Duplicate record found...\nEXITING...\n"
      option=n
    else
      echo "Check failed; do something"
    fi
  done
}
```